# Laravel notifications are saved in the database with null user_id

Tags: database, notifications, laravel-8

When I try to save a notification for a user, the *user_id* column is always NULL in the database.

I have the `Notifiable` trait assigned to the `User` model and this also happens when I use the `Notification` facade. It just doesn't save anything in the *user_id* column.

I get the user through a relationship, something like `$this->buyer->user` where `Buyer` model belongs to `User`. I can see that the user is retrieved properly and has the ID.

```
App\Models\User {#1532
    #fillable: array:5 [
        0 => "name"
        1 => "last_name"
        2 => "email"
        3 => "password"
        4 => "account_type"
    ]
    #hidden: array:4 [
        0 => "password"
        1 => "remember_token"
        2 => "two_factor_recovery_codes"
        3 => "two_factor_secret"
    ]
    #casts: array:1 [
        "email_verified_at" => "datetime"
    ]
    #appends: array:1 [
        0 => "profile_photo_url"
    ]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: "users"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:14 [
        "id" => 20
        "name" => "Test"
        "last_name" => "User"
        "email" => "test _at mail com"
        "email_verified_at" => "2021-03-12 18:17:28"
        "password" => ""
        "two_factor_secret" => null
        "two_factor_recovery_codes" => null
        "remember_token" => null
        "account_type" => "buyer"
        "current_team_id" => null
        "profile_photo_path" => null
        "created_at" => "2021-03-12 18:17:22"
        "updated_at" => "2021-03-12 18:17:53"
    ]
    #original: array:14 [
        "id" => 20
        "name" => "Test"
        "last_name" => "User"
        "email" => "test _at mail com"
        "email_verified_at" => "2021-03-12 18:17:28"
        "password" => ""
        "two_factor_secret" => null
        "two_factor_recovery_codes" => null
        "remember_token" => null
        "account_type" => "buyer"
        "current_team_id" => null
        "profile_photo_path" => null
        "created_at" => "2021-03-12 18:17:22"
        "updated_at" => "2021-03-12 18:17:53"
    ]
    #changes: []
    #classCastCache: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
    ]
    #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
    #accessToken: null
    }
```

I try to send the notification like this:

```
$this->buyer->user->notify(new \App\Notifications\MessageReceived(
    $this->message,
    'user 2')
);
```

The *MessageReceived.php* file looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class MessageReceived extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $message;
    public $sender;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message, $sender)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [ 'broadcast', 'database' ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the broadcastable representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return BroadcastMessage
     */
    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'message' => $this->message,
            'sender' => $this->sender,
            'link' =>  '/chat/'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the type of the notification being broadcast.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastType()
    {
        return 'broadcast.message';
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)->subject('New message received')->view();
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'message' => 'You have a new message from ' . $this->sender,
            'link' => $this->business->id . '/chat/' . $this->channel,
            'type' => 'broadcast.message'
        ];
    }
}
```

When I log the database queries I get this for this operation:

```
  array (
    'query' => 'insert into `notifications` (`id`, `type`, `data`, `read_at`, `notifiable_id`, `notifiable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => '960ec22c-f121-4ef7-acca-c0e6105fd760',
      1 => 'App\\Notifications\\MessageReceived',
      2 => '{"message":"You have a new message from user 2","link":"/chat/","type":"broadcast.message"}',
      3 => NULL,
      4 => 20,
      5 => 'App\\Models\\User',
      6 => '2021-05-20 19:37:20',
      7 => '2021-05-20 19:37:20',
    ),
    'time' => 148.9,
  ),
```

I don't see the `user_id` column in this query. Is this a bug or what could I be doing wrong? I have had this issue for weeks and can't find the culprit. I am using version 8.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user id or notifiable id is stored at the notifiable_id column.
You can get the notifications related to the user using the relation between $user->notifications or $user->unreadNotifications().